# Getting the HOST/URL of a Ruby on Rails app? Extended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I have read the other question with the same title and it doesn't in fact get the URL of the app. It gets the URL of the current page, which is mighty close, and suited the needs of the question perfectly.  Sadly I don't have a current page, or even a controller.

I want to get the HOST/URL of the app. From within a worker DYNO.

I have two "apps" on Heroku right now... one testing and one production.  Well technically both are production, one is beta, the other is released.

I would like to be able to figure out the URL of the app, because I send out data to a third party and I'd like to include a link back to the system (and a specific record)...

More detail:
I have a WORKER send an XML file contain product details to eBay.  In the product details there's space for an HTML compatible "description".. I want to have a link back to my system in there, so a viewer can see details that exceed eBay's ability to display.  Thus I need the URL of my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in ENV / config but you could add it with:

`heroku config:add HOST=warmmist837.herokuapp.com`

or better yet

`heroku config:add BETA=1`

then in code you can say `ENV['HOST']` or `ENV['BETA']`

Typically in rails code i would say `Request.host` but i don't think that will help as you are in a worker not a Rack request.

also if you are worried about working locally with this setup, if you are using RVM as your probably should be you can add the export statement to the .rvmrc

`export HOST=my.localmachine.com`

Answer (score 6):

You can get to the Rails application's routing helpers using this method:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

To access a helper from this module, just call the method on it and pass it a host:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.products_url(:host => "example.com")
```

Comment: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Comment: @daveatflow: Try passing a host option to it as well.

Comment: Ha..   there's the trick.. I don't know the host.  My app runs on a few (two right now but more later) systems, and each has a different host.  Tis what I'd like rails to tell me.

Comment: Well without a context for the request it wont know. A worker wont know anything about the webcontext because there is no request. I recommend you configure it in yaml for you app? or as a constant or a heroku-config

Comment: I was thinking the same @j_mcnally  I was hoping perhaps that heroku had an API call or something.. Like how it's possible to get the location of your database through code.

Comment: that relies on the same thing i said earlier: check "heroku config"